# Transform: Scale a svg path and centering

Tags: css, svg, css-transforms, web-frontend

I am trying to animate a svg world map since hours. I red several artikels and threads about this topic but nothing is working.

I have a SVG World Map, one of it's paths is called Australia.

```
<svg version="1.1" id="World" viewBox="0 0 1920 1080">
      <a href="/Australia" title="Australia" className="nav-link">
        <path
          id="Australia"
          d="M1530.9,867l-66.4,5.4
          c-4.3,0.3-7.9-3.2-7.5-7.5l4.7-60.2c0.3-4,2.6-7.7,6.1-9.7l75.4-43.8c3.2-1.9,7.3-1.4,10,1.2l14.6,14.1c2.7,2.6,6.8,3.1,10.1,1.3
          l12-6.8c4.7-2.7,10.6-1,13.2,3.7l32.5,58.6c2.2,4,2.4,8.9,0.5,13l-24.8,53.2c-1.6,3.5-4.9,6-8.7,6.7l-36.6,6.7
          c-5.2,1-10.4-1.7-12.7-6.5l-11-22.8C1540.2,869.2,1535.7,866.6,1530.9,867z"
        />
      </a>
    </svg>
```

I am trying to animate the Path with css so that it's centered and scaled up to 6.

The Issue is that SVG scales based on the origin location, not the current location, I am attempting to fix this situation by scaling, then translating to center in severalt steps. It's kind of working but the animation is not fluent, due to not optimal centering so it moves in a zic-zac motion rather than fluently scaling up and moving to center.

```
#Australia.clicked {
  animation: Australia-click-animation 2s ease-out forwards;
}

@keyframes Australia-click-animation {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
    stroke-width: 15;
  }
  20% {
    transform: scale(2) translateX(-56%) translateY(-52.5%);
    stroke-width: 7;
  }
  40% {
    transform: scale(3) translateX(-65%) translateY(-60%);
    stroke-width: 7;
  }
  60% {
    transform: scale(4) translateX(-67.5%) translateY(-64%);
    stroke-width: 7;
  }
  80% {
    transform: scale(5) translateX(-71%) translateY(-66.5%);
    stroke-width: 7;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(6) translateX(-72%) translateY(-68.5%);
    stroke-width: 7;
  }
}
```

I tried different ways, first I did it in one step, but this would move the path out of the viewbox to the bottom-righrt, befor centering.

```
@keyframes Australia-click-animation {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
    stroke-width: 15;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(6) translateX(-72%) translateY(-68.5%);
    stroke-width: 7;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find the middle coordinates of the continents in Illustrator or whatever you used to create the svg and put that value as translation-origin value as an inline style to your svg path. For Australia that is:

```
<path
      style="transform-origin: 1547px 826px"
      id="Australia"
```

Remove all translation values from the css animation and use just the scale value.